# toDataURL() not returning valid image unless alert first

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am uploading images from an HTML form and using Image() to resize an image on a canvas.

Here is what I have:

```
var MAX_HEIGHT = 10;
var target = document.getElementById("filesInfo");
var preview = document.getElementById("preview");
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

var render = function(src)
{
    var img = new Image();

    img.onload = function()
    {
        if(img.height > MAX_HEIGHT) 
        {
            img.width *= MAX_HEIGHT / img.height;
            img.height = MAX_HEIGHT;
        }

        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        preview.style.width = img.width + "px";
        preview.style.height = img.height + "px";
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
    };
    img.src = src;
};

function fileSelect(evt) 
{
    var files = evt.target.files;
    var result = '';
    var file;

    for (var i = 0; file = files[i]; i++) 
    {
        if (!file.type.match('image.*')) 
            continue;
        reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e)
        {
            render(e.target.result);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        alert('foo');
        result += '<li>' + file.name + ' ' + file.size 
        + ' bytes <img src="'+document.getElementById("canvas").toDataURL()+'"></li>';

    }
    document.getElementById('filesInfo').innerHTML = '<ul>' + result + '</ul>';
}
```

If I remove alert('foo'), then image data does not come in (it is a blank image).  Only when I insert the alert does it actually work.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is fine , you just have to wait till the loading is done , which the alert forces the code to , cause actually code breaks before alert then continue:

```
reader.readAsDataURL(file);

 reader.onloadend = function () {

    result += '<li>' + file.name + ' ' + file.size + ' bytes <img src="'+document.getElementById("canvas").toDataURL()+'"></li>';



  }
```

source:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader.readAsDataURL

Comment: I tried this, and I still have to put in the alert in the onloadend function to get it to work.

Comment: try result = '<li>' + file.name + ' ' + file.size + ' bytes <img src="'+document.getElementById("canvas").toDataURL()+'"></li>';   , as a single result test

Comment: please send your full code , with the action to trigger the function